# How to upload image using Codeigniter Rest API?

Tags: php, rest, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I was read some answer in stackoverflow about this question, but I still not understand because the answer hasn't specified and make me confuse. I have some code below.

I use REST from https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/

**My Model API**

```
public function upload(){

        $config['upload_path']='./images/';
        $config['allowed_types']='jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size']='2048';
        $config['remove_space']=TRUE;
        $config['overwrite']=TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('id_image')) {
            $return = array(
                'result'=>'success', 
                'file'=> $this->upload->data(), 
                'error'=>'');
                return $return;

        } else {
            $return = array(
                'result'=>'failed',
                'file'=>'',
                'error'=> $this->upload->display_errors());
                return $return;
        }
    }

    public function createMember($upload){

        $data_member = [
            "id_card" => $this->input->post('id_card', true),
            "name" => $this->input->post('name', true),
            "email" => $this->input->post('email', true),
            "id_image" => $upload['file']['file_name']
        ];
        $this->db->insert('member', $data_member);
    }
```

**My Controller API**

```
public function index_post(){

        $upload = $this->Member_model_api->upload();

        if ($this->Member_model_api->createMember($upload) > 0) {
            $this->response([
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'Member Data was Added'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED);
        } else {
               ...
               REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

**Output from Postman**

*Message: Call to undefined method Member_model_api::upload()*

*Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\org\application\controllers\api_controller\Org_member.php*

I hope the other developers give me some reference like my code above, thank you very much.

Comment: What is the name of your Model that you have shared above? Are you including it in your controller?

Comment: Member_model_api.php, that my model name

Comment: You need to load the model before calling any member function.